# Prolog date of birth

Tags: prolog

I am making a family tree type code, and have to add the birthday for each person. 
I listed all the people:

```
male(bob).
male(rob).
male(nick).
male(george).
male(tim).
male(ali).
male(craig).
male(bill).
male(jacob).
male(alen).
male(ben).
male(jason).
male(berry).
male(jack).

%female(person)%
female(sarah).
female(hanna).
female(demi).
female(beth).
female(emily).
female(kristina).
female(skarlet).
female(nichole).
female(johan).
female(alison).
female(alex).
female(maria).
```

and here is my attempt at adding the birthday.

```
birthday(person):-
   age(person,date(day,month,year)).
```

it doesn't work when i search for a persons birthday. Do i need to add the birthday with the persons name like this ?

```
birthday(bob,date(03,10,1994)).
```

Appreciate anybody that helps out :)

Comment: Yes, a fact such as `birthday(bob,date(03,10,1994)).` would be a reasonable representation for a birthday for a person. In your other attempt, keep in mind that in Prolog variables must start with a capital letter. The query `birthday(X)` would be true only if `X = person` and `age(...)` was an asserted fact somewhere.

Comment: just adding it individually like this :

Comment: 'birthday(bob,date(03,10,1994)).'

Comment: For each person, yes.

Comment: Lurker thanks man i really appreciate it works perfectly